# PhoneGap replaces icons/splash-screens with the default

Tags: ios, cordova

When I run an app I have build with Xcode 4 + PhoneGap, PhoneGap somehow replaces the icon*.png and Default*.png before launching it in iOS Simulator.

It doesn't replace the icons/splashes inside the project, just those in the iOS simulator.

How do I stop this behavior, so I can use my own icons?

Comment: Where did you place your pngs ??

Comment: @TDeBailleul I actual can't remember as it was like 3 months ago.

Comment: Yes right, how stupid of me to think you were still stuck :)

Comment: @TDeBailleul However I never solved the problem...

Comment: I have this same issue. @Tyilo have you found a fix for it?

Comment: @Nalum Nope, but I don't use PhoneGap anymore.